# AngularJS CORS don't send all cookies with credential, but jQuery send

Tags: jquery, angularjs, http, cors, angular-resource

I'm using AngularJS v1.2.16 in my frontend. I've created a simple service:

```
app.provider('Site', function () {

  var apiServer = 'http://api.example.com';

  this.$get = ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    var site = $resource(apiServer + '/sites/:action:id', {}, {
      query: {
        withCredentials: true
      },
      checkDomain: {
        method: 'POST',
        withCredentials: true,
        params: {
          action: 'checkDomain'
        }
      },
      save: {
        method: 'PUT',
        withCredentials: true
      }
    });

    return site;
  }];
});
```

When i try to get list of sites in my controller:

```
app.controller('SitesCtrl', ['$scope', 'Site', function ($scope, Site) {
   $scope.sites = Site.query();
}]);
```

Angular doesn't send cookies with request, and I can't get list of sites.

But when I send same request by jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'http://api.example.com/sites',
  xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
  },
  success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

Cookies sent with request and I can get list of sites.

Tell me, please, where is my mistake?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since the `$resource` service is a factory of `$http` have you try to set the `withCredentials` default value to true of your `$httpProvider` in your app config ?

```
.config(function ($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
}
```

Referring to the Angular [docs](https://code.angularjs.org/1.1.2/docs/api/ngResource.$resource), your syntax seems correct for the `withCredentials`.

Comment: This answer solved it for me! I couldn't get it to work unless it was a default.